# Draw line between two button in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I developing a language learning application in c#.
this application has one part that name is matching word by word. in this part i have 2 columns. left column has master word and right column has word meaning. i want user click on button in left column. when release click a line snap to mouse pointer and when click on the meaning line snap to the button of right column like draw line in photoshop or tell me more language learning. thank you.

[image]

Comment: Draw line using [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Canvas` layout for your application.

I dont know your code but i coded [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axdf3.jpg).

In XAML file Canvas control looks like this:

```
<Canvas Name="myCanvas">
    <Button Name="btn1" Content="Asia" Width="100" Height="30" Click="btn1_Click" Canvas.Left="201" Canvas.Top="143"/>
    <Button  Name="btn2" Content="Arabic" Canvas.Left="473" Width="100" Height="30" Canvas.Top="93"/>
</Canvas>
```

In .CS file `btn1_Click` function should implemented like this:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point btn1Point = btn1.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        Point btn2Point = btn2.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        Line l = new Line();
        l.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        l.StrokeThickness = 2.0;
        l.X1 = btn1Point.X + btn1.ActualWidth;
        l.X2 = btn2Point.X;
        l.Y1 = btn1Point.Y + btn1.ActualHeight/2;
        l.Y2 = btn2Point.Y + btn2.ActualHeight / 2;
        myCanvas.Children.Add(l);
    }
```

Comment: There is no Line Class , what is the library that you've used?